# Unable to fetch queues in Live agent button + omni channel

Tags: liveagent, salesforce-id, queue, omnichannel

I am creating a chat button with routing type ="Omni" but unable to get the queues in lookup input field. I have multiple queues in my Org.

[image]

am I missing any permission that needs to done to fetch the queues in lookup box?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queue->select the queue which u r using in omni ->Supported Objects-> select Live Agent session and Transcripts.

Then it will works[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I was able to figure that. Really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't see either of Live Agent Session, Live Chat Transcript, or anything with the words session or transcript. Can you help me add those to the list of 'Available Objects' on this page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Queue Doens't appers on Chat Button LoukUp**

Before creating a queue, you need to create a routing configuration. After that, when you are creating the queue, you must enter the routing configuration you created earlier and add the chat transcription object to the supported objects.

Without this, the queue will not appear in the Chat button search.

---

PT/BR

**Fila não aparece na Pesquisa do Botão do Chat**

Antes de criar uma fila, você precisará criar uma configuração de roteamento. Depois disso, quando estiver criando a fila, você deverá inserir a configuração de roteamento criada anteriormente e adicionar o objeto de transcrição de chat aos objetos suportados.

Sem isso, a fila não aparecerá na pesquisa do botão Chat.